# How can i use enum in one script and another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the first script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightsEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        Forward, Backward
    };

    private Renderer[] renderers;
    private float lastChangeTime;
    private int greenIndex = 0;

    public void LightsEffect(List<GameObject> objects, Color instantiateColor, Color colorEffect)
    {
        renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
        }

        // Set green color to the first one
        greenIndex = 0;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }

    public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, bool changeDirection)
    {
        // Change color each `delay` seconds
        if (Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay)
        {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;

            // Set color of the last renderer to red
            // and the color of the current one to green
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;
            if (changeDirection == true)
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                changeDirection = false;
            }
            greenIndex = (greenIndex + 1) % renderers.Length;
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

In this script i want to use the enum Directions instead the bool in the core method:

```
public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, bool changeDirection)
```

Instead bool changeDirection to use the enum to decide what direction Forward or Backward.

And then to use this script in another one for example in another script i did:

```
public LightsEffects lightseffect;
```

Then in Start:

```
void Start()
{
 lightseffect.LightsEffect(objects, Color.red, Color.green);
}
```

Then in Update i want to decide the direction:

```
void Update()
{
  lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, false);
}
```

But instead false/true i want to use also here Forward/Backward
Maybe something like:

```
lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, lightseffect.Forward);
```

Since false/true not really have a meaning of what it's doing.

Another option is to leave it with false/true but to add a description to the method when the user typing: lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(

When he type ( he will see a description of what the method do and when he will type ,
It will tell him what the false/true will do. But i'm not sure how to make a description for that.

Comment: I see now that if i add in the first script above the method a summary: /// <summary>
    /// Returns testing.
    /// </summary> it will give description to the method. And how do i add a  summary to specific parameter for example the false/true ?

Comment: Ok param name is for specific parameter for example: /// <param name="changeDirection">Changing the lights movement directions - false = forward, true = backward.</param>

Comment: I guess i will stay with that way instead using enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directions` is the name of the enum you're interested in. It's also contained within the `LightsEffects` class.

Thus the way to reference it somewhere else would be `LightsEffects.Directions` and then another dot and then the value (`Forward`,etc). This is similar to a [Fully Qualified Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name), but with part of that scope already declared (whatever import/using that gets you `LightsEffects`).

So your line:

`lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, lightseffect.Forward);`

Becomes:

`lightseffect.LightsEffectCore(0.1f, LightsEffects.Directions.Forward);`

Depending on your IDE, it should even be able to resolve this for you if you had used `Directions.Forward`: your IDE would have noticed the error (unknown reference Directions) and suggested a fix (change to LightsEffects.Directions), I know that Visual Studio does this, as I have a similar case in a project I'm working on now.